# Optimizing string replacement program that uses recursion

Tags: c, strings, recursion, linux

I have the following string replacement program for a string of size 256:

I am replacing the string

> "\'"

with the string

> &**apos**;

Please suggest any modifications if needed or any mistake I have done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int replace_str(char *SrcStr, char *SubStr, char *RepStr, char *FinalStr )
{

    static char buffer[256]="";
    char *TempStr= NULL;
    char *Tmp2 = malloc(250);
    memset(Tmp2,0,256);

    int ret = 0;

    TempStr = strstr(SrcStr, SubStr);

    if ( TempStr )
    {
        memcpy(Tmp2,TempStr,strlen(TempStr));

        strncpy(buffer, SrcStr, TempStr-SrcStr);

        buffer[TempStr-SrcStr] = '\0';
        sprintf(buffer+(TempStr-SrcStr), "%s%s", RepStr, Tmp2+strlen(SubStr));

        puts(buffer);
        free(Tmp2);
        ret = replace_str(buffer, SubStr, RepStr, FinalStr);
    }
    else
    {

        memcpy(FinalStr, buffer , strlen(buffer));

    }
    return ret;
}


int main(void)
{
    char *str1 = malloc(256);
    memset(str1, 0 ,256);
    memcpy(str1, "pra\'dipta\'kumar\'rout",strlen("pra\'dipta\'kumar\'rout"));

    char str2[10] = "&apos;"; 
    char str3[3] = "\'" ;
    char buff[256] ={0};

    replace_str(str1, str3, str2,buff);

    puts(buff);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- Many strange numbers. Why is `Tmp2` only 250 long?
- Why is `buffer` static?
- Why is `Tmp2` not `free`d in the else branch? Most likely the `malloc()` should also only happen in the then branch.
- The `replace_str` function *should* take a length argument for `FinalStr`, now this might cause a buffer overflow.
- Your naming is very strange: Both `TmpStr` and `Tmp2` are temporary strings, but they are named quite different. Better give them proper names.
- `if (TmpStr)` uses implicit boolean conversion of pointers. That's bad practice.
- Your variable naming convention is inconsequent, some are UpperCamelCase, some are lower case.
- Why is there a call to `puts`? The function should work on a string, not print on `stdout`.
- Now that I think about it: Using fixed size `malloc` is generally stupid.
  Either make that dependent on the actual needs or just use `char[256]`.
- Also you might want to use `calloc` instead of `malloc`.
- Potential buffer overflow in `memcpy(Tmp2,TempStr,strlen(TempStr));`
- Potential buffer overflow in `sprintf(buffer+(TempStr-SrcStr), "%s%s", RepStr, Tmp2+strlen(SubStr));`
- Also why are you using `strncpy` and `sprintf` for the same purpose (string concatenation)? You might want to look at `strncat`.
- Unnecessary memory eating: The temporary strings are not needed for the recursion, better free before.
- Similar for buffer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the many issues pointed out by @Fabian, you are overflowing your `Tmp2` buffer as soon as you create it:

```
char *Tmp2 = malloc(250);
memset(Tmp2,0,256);
```

You're creating a buffer of 250 bytes and then initialising 256 bytes which will overflow into whatever is next in memory.

You also seem to be making things unnecessarily complicated.

```
char *str1 = malloc(256);
memset(str1, 0 ,256);
memcpy(str1, "pra\'dipta\'kumar\'rout",strlen("pra\'dipta\'kumar\'rout"));
```

Could simply be:

```
char str1[256] = "pra\'dipta\'kumar\'rout";
```